# macOS apache installs on different directory with homebrew, how to start/stop?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apache

Im strugling to understand different installations of apache on macOS.
As i now can say i have two installations of apache2 one in
/private/etc/apache2 ->this one seams to be installed by default with the system
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4 ->this one i install with brew

if i `brew install/uninstall httpd24` it un/installs a symlink in /usr/local/bin/apachectl that makes the brew server under /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4 start. But as i read (if i understand correctly) macOS comes with apache in /private/etc/apache2 wich when already running and i install brew it doesn't take the apachectl commands anymore... so im not able to stop it until i `brew uninstall httpd24` and then `sudo apachectl stop`.

i can reach localhost:80 ->system apache
and localhost:8080 -> brew apache

so how can i controll the system apache when i have brew version installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR; Use `/usr/sbin/apachectl`

The issue is that you have bins for both versions, and as they have the same name. Your `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile` configuration will determine the order bin folder are included, which determines which wins.

It's generally a good idea to `/usr/local/bin` win, as this is stuff you installed yourself and not something that comes with the OS by default.

The location of the `apachectl` script for the apache installed on macOS is located in `/usr/sbin`, so you can run it directly using `/usr/sbin/apachectl`. Alternately you can make an alias or symlink for this to make a unique command.